# Setting fields in Django form, when using ModelForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

My model is that I have a list of jobs, and each job can only be done by a subset of users (ManyToManyField).  People can then submit job requests, and assign the job to someone from the subset of people who can do the job:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    ...
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)

class Job_Request(models.Model):
    ...
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job)
    assigned_to = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I then created a form using ModelForm, to allow people to edit the job request, to reassign the job to someone else.  My problem, is that ModelForm creates a menu for the "assigned_to" field in the form, which lists all of our users.  I only want it to show the subset of users that can do that job.  How can I do this?

Below is my forms.py, where I tried setting the assigned_to field to the subset of users that can do the job, but I don't know the correct syntax.  The following is definitely wrong, as it creates an empty menu.  How can I do this, either in the form, or the template?  Thanks.

```
class EditJobRequestForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditJobRequestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['assigned_to'].queryset =
            User.objects.filter(username__in=self.instance.job.users.all()]
```

Comment: what about: `self.fields['assigned_to'].queryset = self.instance.job.users.all()` ? Remember that job must be set in instance before send model to form.

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks!  You saved me, as I was running out of places on the wall that haven't been banged by my head.  I'm hadn't properly understood self and instances.  Now on to more fun.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.fields['assigned_to'].queryset = self.instance.job.users.all()
```

Remember that job must be set in instance before send model to form

Answer (score 0):

```
        User.objects.filter(username__in=self.instance.job.users.all()]
```

You're querying against usernames vs PKs. Of course there is no match.

```
        User.objects.filter(pk__in=self.instance.job.users.all()]
```